# how to select records which pertains to the current month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (attendance) which stores attendance data for employees.Every day , the admin logs in into his system , selects the date(on that date) and marks an employee as present or absent for that date . These records are stored in the attendance table .

I want to retrieve all records for a particular `EmpId` for  the current month  where attendance is marked either `present / absent` .

The column names of attendance table are :

```
1.EmpId - numeric
2.date:date type
3.status(either present/absent)-varchar
```

- I want to write a query for retrieving all records for a particular `EmpId`(say 1) for the current month where `status="present"`
- I want to write another query for retrieving all records for a particular `EmpId`(say 1) for the current month where `status="absent"`

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Nothing's stopping you. Please share what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this query and it works perfect :

```
select * from attendance
where emp_id=1 and year(date)=year(curdate()) and month(date)=month(curdate()) and status='present';
```

Comment: In what way is "your" solution different from the others? It is a bit unfair to mark your answer as accepted when it is the same as the other answers provided to you previously.

Comment: @shadow..i am new to stackoverflow..the solution is exactly the same as that provided by you ...i have added the answer to let you know that the query is what i tried out and it works perfect..i know i shouldn't have marked it as accepted ..will keep that in mind henceforth..thks once again..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [year() and month()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions to get the records fom the current month:

```
select * from attendance
where empid=... and year(date)=year(curdate()) and month(date)=month(curdate()) and status=...
```

You need to provide the employee id and the status from your application.

Comment: If the above helped you to resolve the issue, then pls mark the answer as accepted, indicating to other viewers that the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select * from attendance
where date >= 'YOUR DATE' AND date <= 'YOUR DATE' AND status='Present OR Absent(Any)'
```

OR You can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM attendance
WHERE Status='Present OR Absent(Any)' AND date BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to extract the current month and date from the table and get the results.

Use This query to retrieve the output.

> To Fetch the Present Students Alone

```
$query_one = "SELECT EmpId  FROM `attendance` WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)='".date('Y')."' AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)='".date('m')."' AND `status`='present'";
```

> To Fetch the Absent Students Alone

```
$query_two = "SELECT EmpId  FROM `attendance` WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)='".date('Y')."' AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)='".date('m')."' AND `status`='absent'";
```

The above code will retrieve all the records corresponding to current month and year.

Answer (score 0):

Use can simply use this to achieve the desired output.

```
MONTH(DateColumn) = MONTH(GETDATE())
YEAR(DateColumn)= YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Comment: And what happens if you have attendance data for more than 1 year?